# SQL Server encrypted columns breaks ajax call

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, encryption

I am using encryption in SQL Server. I have an encryption in place for password column, I open the symmetric key, get password value and then close symmetric key at the end of query.

Encrypted password is like this weird text

```
³4×j?×\%¯Ë™S×…-V¯ N HUµ±Êßû­$þ·?BZ1…r9Èô‰¸ŒúÈ%Ì³°§—×âI
```

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
      method: "GET"
      , url: collectionPath
      , success: function(data){temp = data;}
      , error: function(xhr,exception){
        console.log(xhr);
      }
      , dataType: "json"
      , async:false
});
```

`collectionpath` is the path of a coldfusion `cfc` file, this file calls a stored procedure which returns encrypted  password value to ajax call.

When I do an ajax call to get this password field from database, I do see that the call is complete however what is interesting is it goes to error function of ajax call and it has `statuscode=200` in `xhr object` and I see `responsetext` is the `password` field. When I `console.log(exception)`, it says `parseerror`.

Does anybody know how can I get an encrypted field(this is a database encryption and not on code level) value via ajax call?

I can provide more information if needed. But basically what I am trying to do is get the password value and show it in password column on a `my profile` form and user can then update their information. I don't want to pass plain text password for obvious reasons. Please help!!

Comment: Wild guess `dataType: 'json'`... Why are you storing passwords? Also, post some code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have `dataType:'json'` added to call. Just edited my question to add ajax call code. Storing passwords because it's a login system and I need it for authentication purpose

Comment: Authentication is something that is best suited on backend. You don't provide auth on frontend. This is not a good idea unless you have both salt and pepper. Even if encrypt it using salt and pepper, you are basically telling the hacker that *hey, you just signup using *abcd123* and the password saved to db is *someRandomText*, now it's your responsibility to know how we are encrypting the password to save in DB.* Trust me, if the way of encryption is standard, the hacker will figure out the salt and pepper.

Comment: I am doing authentication in backend. My coldfusion component files handle all the authentication process. I need to get the password after the fact that a user is authenticated, I need it when displaying `my profile` section in admin area. I was just answering a question about why I store password, I never said I was authenticating using html or some frontend technology(unless I am missing something here)? I have always done authentication this way, am I missing something?